# React; Set Default Date Range value in UseState and ensure get setup value and not previously assigned

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I need to calculate date range based on todays date. I have define two const variable for startDate and endDate. I am calculating date range value and assigning to it but the issue is I get previously assigned value and not newly set default date value at time making API call. I am calculating default date range in setDefaultDateRange  method/ function

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date('01-17-2021'));
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date('02-17-2021'));

 useEffect(() =>{
 setInitialPageLoad(true);
 setDefaultDateRange();
},[setEziSearchCriteria]);

const setDefaultDateRange =()=>{
  let todayDate = new Date();
  let previousDateRange = moment(todayDate).subtract(7, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  setEndDate(todayDate);
  setStartDate(new Date(previousDateRange));
 }
```

Comment: where are you makinng the api call?

Comment: In same component

Comment: Sounds like you are making the API call before the asynchronous state has updated. Without including more detail about the API call in the question it's not really answerable, but making the call in an effect listening for changes to `startDate` or `endDate` is likely the solution.

Comment: We need more info about the API call. I should be in a useEffect which has the startDate/endDate in its dependency array. Once they update the API is triggered.

I would suggest you use only one useState with an array [startDate, endDate] because you handle them together anyway.